# color picker function working upside down

Tags: javascript, jquery

1 quick problem basically my function is working however it only works when I click on actual color picker and not the button however I would like to modify that function in a different way so it works like this.

1.User clicks on a color they want to use.
2.When they click on a div it applies choosen color as a background.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var storage;
$("#changeColor").click(function(){
    $("#colorChoice").click(function(){
  $('#' + storage).css('background', $(this).val());
  });
});
  $('#content-link2').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    storage = ($(e.target).attr("id"));
  });
});

<input type="color" id="colorChoice">
<button id="changeColor" class="btn-primary pull-right">Change</button>
```

So, my question is how could that function be modified to work as intended?

Comment: You should not nest click functions. You set the click function for colorChoice inside the click function of changeColor.

Comment: I had it seperated but it didn't work either for some reason

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for - something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/3uvr3srf/

Comment: Yes! Exactly like this! just to confirm is it possible to add more html tags so if I only change background color just for div at the moment, if I add body to it will it still work?

Comment: It will work, but the click handler is currently binded to the divs inside content, so you need to click there in case you want to set a color.

Comment: How could a click handler be modified so that I can change background color of anything inside #content-link2?

Comment: `.on('click','*',function() {});`

Comment: I still cannot change body background color with this

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer your question(s):

*First*: You shouldn't nest a click function into another click function. Like this you "initialize" the event listener of the color field each time you click on your button.

*Second*: By Using `click` on the color input field you listen to the event when you open the dialog, not when you set/ select the color. You should use the `input` event instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var storage;
    $("#colorChoice").on('input',function(){
      storage = $(this).val();
    });
  $('#content-link2').on('click','div',function(e) {
    $(this).css('background',storage);
  });
});
```

*Third*: How to change the background color on different elements. I am not sure what you want to do - but if you want to change the background-color of the body when you click on it, you can do something like this:

```
// change the body background by clicking anywhere (inside the body)
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).css('background',storage);
});
```

If you want to add this functionality to all elements inside a container you could use the wild-card selector:

```
// would add the click handler to all elements which are inside 
// an element with the ID content-link2.
$('#content-link2').on('click','*',function(e) {

});
```

Or you can bundle a set of different selectors, for example:

```
$('#YourColorSetButton').on('click','*',function(e) {
    $('body, #content-link2, #content-link3').css('background',storage);
});
```

To complete this answer, here is the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/3uvr3srf/1/) from the comment above.